# How to use ' in alias?

Tags: shell-script, quoting, alias, escape-characters

I have one-line that I want to call using alias.

`while printf '%s ' "$(df -P / | awk 'NR==2 { print $(NF-1) }')"; do sleep 30; done`

I tried to escape `'` like `\'` but it didn't work.

What is the correct syntax to use above one-liner in alias?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
alias my_du=$'while printf \'%s \' "$(df -P / | awk \'NR==2 { print $(NF-1) }\')"; do sleep 3; done'
```

You can check the result with

```
alias my_du
```

If `$()` is quoted by `"` instead of `'` or `\` then it is substituted and the result rather than the intended program call becomes part of the alias definition.

Comment: Works smoothly, thank you. Could you explain to me `$` at the beginning?

Comment: @Radek Have a look at the man page, block "QUOTING" (starting on line 341 here). `$''` is a special kind of quoting which does not just quote but also enables escape sequences (like printf, e.g. `$'\n'` for newline). That is actually the more important part than the better quoting of `'`. Everyone who does shell scripting (with bash) should be familiar with this.

Answer (score 5):

While this can be coaxed into an alias, functions are generally preferred. From `man bash`:

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

Your alias in function form:

```
my_du() {
    while printf '%s ' "$(df -P / | awk 'NR==2 { print $(NF-1) }')"
    do
        sleep 30
    done
}
```

That's more readable, and as such more maintainable.

Answer (score 4):

You can't escape single quotes whilst still in single quotes because `\` is taken literally in a single quote context. Either close the single quotes before escaping, or, better, use double quotes.

```
alias my_du="while printf '%s ' \"\$(df -P / | awk 'NR==2 { print \$(NF-1) }')\"; do sleep 30; done"
```

Comment: That is not completely correct: `echo $'\''`

Comment: @HaukeLaging `$'` and `'` are totally different, and not related -- `$'` is definitely not suitable in this situation. You might as well compare `"` and `$"`.

Comment: You should have a look at `alias my_du` to see what your proposal does. Why that does not work. Or you may run `strace -p $PID -f -e trace=process` against the shell and run the alias and wonder why neither df nor awk get executed. Funny that you call $' "definitely not suitable in this situation" because that one does work.

Comment: @ChrisDown, Hauke Laging has a good point: you forgot to escape the `$` signs, so the command substitution takes place when the alias is defined, not when is executed.

Comment: Someone tells you about strace test results and you don't even check the output of `alias my_du` as advised? Wow, what a self-confidence. Your definition of "works" is funny. Indeed, your code creates that output. I didn't doubt that. It just does not change the output if the file system situation changes.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, I also got the meaning of your words only after `dd`ing a 10Gb++ temporary file…

Comment: @HaukeLaging Apologies, I found what you were saying to be unclear.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a backslash to escape a single quote inside a single-quoted string because the backslash itself is interpreted literally.

You can effectively escape a single quote inside a single-quoted string by writing the 4-character sequence `'\''`. Formally this terminates the single-quoted literal, appends a literal single quote, and starts a new single-quoted literal. The end result is that you have a single quote character in the middle of a single-quoted literal.

```
alias foo='while printf '\''%s '\'' "$(df -P / | awk '\''NR==2 { print $(NF-1) }'\'')"; do sleep 30; done'
```

I wouldn't recommend such a complex alias. Aliases are primarily meant to give a short name to a command, possibly with switches. This goes well beyond their comfort range. Use a function instead.

```
foo () {
  while printf '%s ' "$(df -P / | awk 'NR==2 { print $(NF-1) }')"; do sleep 30; done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want commands that take arguments or interact in any way with their environment, use functions. At least in bash, aliases are expanded when defined, they *might* act as if they took arguments or used variables. Sometimes. Murphy's law ensures that that won't work when really needed.